# Proc ARIMA with a delay in receiving actuals

Tags: sql, sas, forecasting

I'm hoping to develop an ARIMA model in SAS using the Proc ARIMA statement, however we do not receive the the actuals until 4 days after the date we are forecasting for (e.g. D+4). Because of this I need to be able to get the ARIMA model to use lagged values from D-4 and back rather than D-1 and back as it currently does.

Is there an option to do this built in or will I need to do some manipulation of dates and actuals etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code and an example dataset, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not continue to use the full data but only look at the D+4 forecast?

```
title1 'Simulated IMA(1,1) Series';
data test;
  u1 = 0.9; a1 = 0;
  do i = -50 to 100;
     a = rannor( 32565 );
     u = u1 + a - .8 * a1;
     if i > 0 then output;
     a1 = a;
     u1 = u;
  end;
run;

/*Last date observed was 100, want the forecast for 104*/
proc arima data=test ;
  identify var=u(1);
  estimate q=1 ;
  forecast id=i interval=day out=forecast(where=(i=104));
quit;
```